# creating a rotating 3d shape in opengl with proper clipping

Tags: opengl, enthought, pyglet, canopy, depth-buffer

I'm trying to create a triangular pyramid that rotates constantly. I've taken some code from a tutorial example to get the rotation and I think it's working, but my figure is getting clipped in the z axis. From what I've seen in a variety of tutorials, forums, etc., openGL has a default z range of (-1, 1). How can I change this to display the full extent of my figure?

Thanks (and here's my code)

```
import pyglet

from pyglet.gl import *

rx = ry = rz = 0

config = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4, depth_size=1000, double_buffer=True,)
win = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True, config=config)

@win.event

def update(dt):
    global rx, ry, rz
    rx += dt * 1
    ry += dt * 80
    rz += dt * 30
    rx %= 360
    ry %= 360
    rz %= 360
pyglet.clock.schedule(update)

@win.event
def on_draw():

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(200, 200, -4)
    glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1)
    glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0)
    glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0)


    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)

    glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0, 200.0, 0.0)

    glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -100.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 200.0, 0.0)

    glVertex3f(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -100.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 200.0, 0.0)

    glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -100.0)
    glVertex3f(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glEnd()

    glLoadIdentity()
    #glTranslatef(1.5, 0.0, -10.0)          

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of what it means when you say "clipped on the z-axis"? I'm not familiar with that term

Comment: glOrtho for the version of OpenGL you are using.

Comment: can't post an image apparently since my 'reputation' isn't high enough.

Comment: where should i implement glOrtho? i tried putting it into 'on_draw' but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

*OpenGL has matrices for Projection and ModelView.*

What you want is to change the Projection Matrix from the default one to a more appropriate one.

Instead of

```
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(200, 200, -4)
```

Write

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(-1000, 1000, -1000, 1000, -1000, 1000)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(200, 200, -4)
```

Where `glOrtho(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min, z_max)` is the most likely implementation you will get.

If you want a 3d Projection, use `gluPerspective`